# Hide / remove columns from certain users in a SSAS tabular model

Tags: ssas, tabular

I've got a nice SSAS tabular model with users processing away. Certain users need access to certain information, such as confidential info (e.g., SS numbers), that should not be visible to everyone. How should I handle this?

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96e6ffdd-7600-4a5d-ba23-4174e352e492/ssas-tabular-security-on-specific-field-rather-than-row-level?forum=sqlanalysisservices) indicates that there is no way to use roles to remove columns, only rows. Is my only option to make a copy of the model and maintain both? This can't be such an edge case...

I guess I can jury-rig something with a scm fork and code-generation, but I'd rather not go down that road.

Alternatively, is there any way to hide the columns (per user/role), so that at least they don't show up in client tools?

Answer (score 1):

One method that requires very little additional development is to use the method described in the following blog post. http://blog.westmonroepartners.com/a-workaround-for-column-security-in-the-sql-server-analysis-services-bism-tabular-model/

The blog contains a link to an SSIS package which will replicate an existing cube, with the exception of the sensitive data columns.  The users who cannot view the sensitive data columns can be given access to the second cube that does not contain sensitive data columns.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to create [Perspectives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492105.aspx). You can create different perspectives for different group of users. And end users can connect to their specific model.

Comment: Please expand your answer, it is very susceptible to link rot.

Comment: Thanks EICaptain I will try to follow it.